How to refer to a library in an interface?
The below code is a function of my smart contract. As you can see, its return data refers to a library. VoteLibrary is a library, and VoteCounting is a struct defined within it. Therefore, VoteLibrary.VoteCounting[] is an array that its elements are instances of the VoteCounting struct, which is defined within the VoteLibrary library.
How should I add this function to an interface?
Function code:
function countVote() external view returns(VoteLibrary.VoteCounting[] memory) {
    // Instantiation of an array with type of the library's struct
    VoteLibrary.VoteCounting[] memory voteCountingArray;
    voteCountingArray = new VoteLibrary.VoteCounting[](candidateCounter);
    for (uint8 i = 0 ; i < candidateCounter ; i++) {
        voteCountingArray[i] = VoteLibrary.VoteCounting(candidateList[i + 1].voteID, candidateList[i + 1].voteCount);
    }
    return VoteLibrary.voteCounter(voteCountingArray);
}


Provided that your VoteLibrary is defined in a file (say VoteLibrary.sol), like:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

// Example definition of the VoteLibrary and the VoteCounting struct
library VoteLibrary {
    struct VoteCounting {
        uint256 voteID;
        uint256 voteCount;
    }

    function voteCounter(VoteCounting[] memory votes)
        internal
        pure
        returns (VoteCounting[] memory)
    {
        // Implementation of voteCounter (if needed)
        return votes;
    }
}

You can import the VoteLibrary in your interface and access its VoteCounting struct and use the array of VoteCounting as the return type of the corresponding countVote function of the interface, like:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {VoteLibrary} from "./VoteLibrary.sol";

// Interface definition
interface IVoteCounting {
    function countVote()
        external
        view
        returns (VoteLibrary.VoteCounting[] memory);
}

